# When uploading a file, size of AJAX request is much larger than the original size

Tags: javascript, ajax, base64

I have a simple file upload funcitonality in place using knockout, in my durandal website. I upload the file to the server by converting the file to a base64StringArray, then uploading the file using an AJAX post method, i.e.

```
$.post("localhost/uploadDocument", dataToPost)
```

I have the following request filtering in place in my application:

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="31457280" />
```

and

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="30720" />
```

So I have about a 30mb file limit.

The problem I am having is with a specific Microsoft Excel file, which also includes some embedded PDF files. This file is 14,887,424 bytes, but when I upload it through my application, Fiddler shows that 49,158,346 bytes were sent, therefore I receive a 404.13 error - where the request is denied due to exceeding the request content length.

Why are so many bytes being sent for this one Excel file with embedded PDF files?

Comment: I would try removing the embedded files momentary and retry to see if the embedded files are the problem.

Comment: Looks like the issue is the embedded PDF's. Even if I have a single embedded PDF file, the size of the Excel file is about 4,052,992 bytes whereas the number of bytes sent in the request are about 13,076,491.

Answer (score 1):

I would compress the string client side using something like:

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#JavaScript

and then on the server side, decompress it, and perform whatever validation you might be doing to check file size